# Запятые для определений как прилагательные

Tags: пунктуация

Я так и насчёт эти прилагательних, после слов, к которым они относятся, стоящих, ничего и не понял. В 4-м пункте всё чёрным по белому сказано (не надо их обособлять, если без них пропадает суть): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109. Но меня вы разными мнениями запутали. Где нужны запятые?

> Наш офис(,) ближайший к вам(,) находится в 30 км.

> Офис(,) ближайший к вам(,) находится в 30 км.

> Я не знаю, когда-нибудь ли я ещё видел девушку(,) ещё красивее, чем вы.

> Я не видел кота(,) самого большого в этом районе.

> Я видел котика(,) в тридцать шесть с полониной раз меньше этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Документы на продажу вашей 5-комнатной квартиры нужно оформить в офисе. *Наш Офис, **ближайший к вАм**, находится в 30 км.*

У нас много офисов. *Офис, **ближАйший к вам,** находится в 30 км.*

*Я не знаю, когда-нибудь ли я видел дЕвушку, **ещё красИвее, чем вы.*** Вы так прекрасны!

*Я не знаю, когда-нибудь ли я видел девушку **ещЁ красивее, чем вы.***  Вы всех прекраснее, уверяю вас.

*Я не видел котА, **самого большОго в этом районе.*** Он все время где-то прячется.

*Я не видел кота  **самого большОго в этом районе.*** Все примерно одинаковые.

Котики рАзные бывают. *Я видел кОтика, / **в тридцать шесть с половиной раз мЕньше этого.*** Я его даже не разглядел.

Этот котик мАленький? *Я видел котика / **в тридцать шесть с половиной раз мЕньше этого.***  Но, может, это был не котик...

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** (из https://orfoschool.ru/page_81818/ ,  также https://orfoschool.ru/page_81817/)

– А чем **принципиально отличаются** правила обособления **согласованных** определений и **несогласованных** определений, выраженных падежными формами существительных?

– **Во-первых**, у этих определений **разная нормальная позиция**: для согласованных определений это позиция **перед** определяемым словом, а для несогласованных определений – **после** определяемого слова.

Соответственно, надо использовать разные **правила обособления**, которые **во многом** зависят от позиции определительных оборотов.

**Во-вторых,** в инверсированной позиции (перед определяемым словом и на расстоянии) несогласованные определения обособляются практически **всегда** (нет исключений).

**В-третьих,** на обособление несогласованных определений их **распространенность** оказывает значительное влияние, в отличие от согласованных определений, где распространенность только учитывается.

Что касается **логических ударений**, то правила обособления  **похожи:** при обособлении ударение падает **и на существительное, и на оборот**; без обособления в ударной позиции находится **только оборот**.

Comment: В примере про котика у вас нет нигде запятой.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено. Хороший вопрос, Лео,  над вариантами пришлось подумать.  Но у вас, как я вижу, появились конкуренты)

Comment: Who is that? Max?

Comment: Yes, it's him, but not only...

Comment: We ain't gonna be competing against each other. Mr. Leopold, that is me, is a wise kitten, so, in my opinion, it would be best if we became collaborators. Don't you think so?

Comment: I'm only for cooperation! But competition is different. It makes our work more interesting, intrigue appears! And now I do not know which horse to bet on... Or maybe we already have three new horses?..